# same name for extended class php

Tags: php, class, extends

I am trying to create a php class that will take in data from multiple child classes and display the value at the end

```
class ManifestBuilder
{

  static $manifest;

  function __construct( )
  {
    $this->get_manifest( );
  }

  function get_manifest( )
  { 
    include 'manifest.php';
    include 'sub1/manifest.php';
    include 'sub2/manifest.php';
    var_dump ( ManifestBuilder::$manifest ); 
  }

  function add_manifest( $var )
  {
    ManifestBuilder::$manifest .= $var;
  }


}

new ManifestBuilder( );
```

Each child looks like this

```
class Manifest extends ManifestBuilder 
{

  function __construct( )
  {
    $this->manifest( );
  }

  function manifest( )
  {

    parent::add_manifest( 'manifest1' );

  }

}

new Manifest( );
```

The problem is that I want to name the class the same on each child so I can easily move them around, but I am getting an error that class names cannot be the same (expected).

How can I solve this? I want to have multiple child classes be able to add to a variable in the parent class.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve. Why do you need children with the same class name?

Comment: I would think you'd make things more *complicated* with multiple identical class names, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's as simple as that.

And it makes sense too. If you need further functionality on the same class, simply refactor it. If you need a child class, extend it.